# How do I enter date inside @html.textboxfor look like this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working in MVC 5, with HTML 5. How can I enter date look like below image?

[image]

Comment: Use a jquery masked input plugin

Comment: I Think [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642477/Input-Masking-in-MVC-using-Data-Annotation) must help you to complete your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this, first all two libraries in head

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

then below will be your textbox

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateOfBirth,  new { @class = "form-control", @id = "DateOfBirth" } )
```

here `x.DateOfBirth` will be the property of type `DateTime` and your script will be

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#DateOfBirth").mask("99/99/9999");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery mask plugin seems very clean and may help:

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Your Html.TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DOB, new { @class = "date" })
```

Then your jQuery will be simply:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
    });
</script>
```